# Returning a Future from Service bean and doing Ok.sendEntity in Play/Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a service bean that I wrote and it looks like this

```
def myStream(name: String): HttpEntity.Streamed = {

}
```

In my controller I am able to use it as:

```
def myControllerHandler(id: Name) = Action {
  Ok.sendEntity(myStream(id))
}
```

I want to change the signature of my service method as

```
def myStream(name: String):Future[HttpEntity.Streamed] = {

}
```

Then in my controller, the below code fails to compile, and I am unable to find a way to make it work

```
def downloadLocalBackup(name: String) = Action {
  myStream(name) map { fileStream =>
    Ok.sendEntity(fileStream)
  }
}
```

The reason this fails is because Action can take `Result` type but not `Future[Result]`.

How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Action.async`:

```
def downloadLocalBackup(name: String) = Action.async {
  myStream(name) map { fileStream =>
    Ok.sendEntity(fileStream)
  }
}
```

From play documentation:

> While we were using the `Action.apply` builder method to build actions
>   until now, to send an asynchronous result we need to use the
>   `Action.async` builder method:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync

Comment: Thanks, how dumb of me to miss that basic thing from documentation!